# My sinch client posts duplicate messages into parse database

Tags: android, sinch

My sinch client sends duplicate messages to my parse database in an incremental way. That is for the first message it posts once in the database. Twice for the second message. Thrice for the third in that order.

This is my ChatActivity

```
   package com.app.knowtes;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.PushPair;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.Message;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClient;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageDeliveryInfo;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageFailureInfo;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.WritableMessage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by RR on 12/6/2015.
 */
public class ChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    private String recipientId;
    private EditText messageBodyField;
    private String messageBody;
    private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
    private String currentUserId;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
    ListView messagesList;
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatactivity);

        bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //get recipientId from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);
        messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);

        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        String[] cuserIds = {currentUserId, recipientId};
        String[] ruserIds = {recipientId,currentUserId};
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
        query.whereContainedIn("senderId", Arrays.asList(cuserIds));
        query.whereContainedIn("recipientId", Arrays.asList(ruserIds));
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                        WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(messageList.get(i).get("recipientId").toString(), messageList.get(i).get("messageText").toString());
                        if (messageList.get(i).get("senderId").toString().equals(currentUserId)) {
                            messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                        } else {
                            messageAdapter.addMessage(message, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //listen for a click on the send button
        findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //send the message!
                messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
                if (messageBody.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }else {
                    messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
                    messageBodyField.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
    }
    //unbind the service when the activity is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        messageService.removeMessageClientListener(new MyMessageClientListener());
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
            messageService.addMessageClientListener(new MyMessageClientListener());
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            messageService = null;
        }
    }


    private class MyMessageClientListener implements MessageClientListener {
        //Notify the user if their message failed to send
        @Override
        public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                                    MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message failed to send." + failureInfo.getSinchError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
            //Display an incoming message
            if (message.getSenderId().equals(recipientId)) {
                WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
                messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, final String recipientId) {
            //Display the message that was just sent
            //Later, I'll show you how to store the
            //message in Parse, so you can retrieve and
            //display them every time the conversation is opened
            //WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
            //messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message successfully senT.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
            messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);

            //only add message to parse database if it doesn't already exist there
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
            query.whereEqualTo("sinchId", message.getMessageId());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (messageList.size() == 0) {
                            ParseObject parseMessage = new ParseObject("ParseMessage");
                            parseMessage.put("senderId", currentUserId);
                            parseMessage.put("recipientId", recipientId);
                            parseMessage.put("messageText", writableMessage.getTextBody());
                            parseMessage.put("sinchId", writableMessage.getMessageId());
                            parseMessage.saveInBackground();
                            messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }


        //Do you want to notify your user when the message is delivered?
        @Override
        public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {}
        //Don't worry about this right now
        @Override
        public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {}
    }
}
```

And this is my MessageService.java

```
package com.app.knowtes;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.ClientRegistration;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.Sinch;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchClient;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.SinchError;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClient;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.WritableMessage;

/**
 * Created by RR on 12/4/2015.
 */
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
    private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
    private MessageClient messageClient = null;
    private String currentUserId;
    private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.app.knowtes.ChatListActivity");
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //get the current user id from Parse
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        }

        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public void startSinchClient(String username) {
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
                .context(this)
                .userId(username)
                .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT)
                .build();
        //this client listener requires that you define
        //a few methods below
        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);
        //messaging is "turned-on", but calling is not
        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        sinchClient.checkManifest();
        sinchClient.start();
    }
    private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
    }
    //The next 5 methods are for the sinch client listener
    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        sinchClient = null;

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        sinchClient = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {}
    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {}
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceInterface;
    }
    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            messageClient.send(message);
        }
    }
    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }
    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
        //sinchClient.stop();
        sinchClient.terminate();
    }
    //public interface for ListUsersActivity & MessagingActivity
    public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }
        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
        public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
        }
        public void terminateSinchClient(){

        }
    }

}
```

enter code here

Comment: Show your work, we have now way of helping you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you log out, our servers dont know that the messages have been delivered to that device. We keep messages for delivery for 30 days. AS a developer you will experience this more since you are wiping the install when you deploy.

If you just kill the app and launch it again you will see that its not delivered again.

There is a couple of ways of avoiding this, 
1. Dont log out
2. If you want logout functionality, dont toast as old messages arrive look at time stamp.
or keep track of messages id in your own database

Comment: So what is the solution this problem please.